# Iterable sorting by key-occurrence is overwriting when same occurence appears twice Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, overwrite, iterable

I have created an Iterable in Java that sort keys by their occurrence in decending order. For example if I have this array: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1] I will get the output 3 2 1. Though there is one problem with my code. Whenever the occurrence of a key appears twice it overwrites the old one. For example if i have this array: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0] I will get the output 3 1 0 when I want ot get 3 2 1 0. Here is what my Iterable looks like:

```
Iterable<Key> keys()
    {
        ArrayList<Key> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> occurrenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Key> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Key>();
        ArrayList <Key> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        int j = 0;

        //puts keys in one arraylist and occurrences in another arraylist
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (keys[i] != null)
            {
                keyList.add((Key) keys[i].getKey());
                occurrenceList.add(keys[i].counter);
            }
        }

        //puts each key and occurrence in a treemap so that they are "linked"
        //This is where the overwriting is happening
        for(Integer num : occurrenceList)
        {
            sortedMap.put(occurrenceList.get(j), keyList.get(j));
            j++;
        }

        //puts the key values in another arraylist in the sorted order from the sortedMap
        for(Key s : sortedMap.values())
        {
            temp.add(s);
        }

        //flips it to decending order
        Collections.reverse(temp);

        return temp;
    }
```

This is where the problem happens:

```
for(Integer num : occurrenceList)
        {
            sortedMap.put(occurrenceList.get(j), keyList.get(j));
            j++;
        }
```

And this is how i test my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinearProbingHashSet<Integer> list = new LinearProbingHashSet<>(30);

        list.insert(3);
        list.insert(3);
        list.insert(3);
        list.insert(2);
        list.insert(2);
        list.insert(1);

        for(int i : list.keys())
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

It is also worth noting that I am not using a Key array but rather a HashElement array. Hashelement is my own class that looks like this:

```
public class HashElement<Key> implements Comparable<HashElement<Key>> {
    Key key;
    int counter;

    HashElement(Key key)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.counter = 1;
    }

    HashElement(Key key, int counter)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    int getFrequency()
    {
        return this.counter;
    }

    Key getKey()
    {
        return this.key;
    }

    public int compareTo(HashElement that) {
        if(this.counter > that.counter)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(this.counter < that.counter)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I know my code is probably not optimised but right now I want to focus on getting it to work. Also I am not 100% sure what I am doing. How would you go about fixing the overwrite problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  You are missing some code.

Comment: There, I think I added what you asked for.

Comment: A [mre] is something that can compile and run.  I don't see `LinearProbingHashSet` defined.  And I see you are inserting the values in descending order.  Is that required?

Comment: If you had this array `(3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2)` in that order, what output would you be looking for?

Comment: I would expect [5, 3, 2, 0, 1]

Comment: That's what I thought.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code lies in this statement:

```
sortedMap.put(occurrenceList.get(j), keyList.get(j));
```

Consider the `array = [3,3,3,2,2,1,1,0]`, when this part executes

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (keys[i] != null)
        {
            keyList.add((Key) keys[i].getKey());
            occurrenceList.add(keys[i].counter);
        }
    }
```

The **keyList** is [3, 2, 1, 0], and **occurrenceList** is [3, 2, 2, 1].

Now, when you try to put the elements of **occurrenceList** in a map, like this:

```
for(Integer num : occurrenceList)
    {
        sortedMap.put(occurrenceList.get(j), keyList.get(j));
        j++;
    }
```

The 2 at index-2 in occurrenceList, overrides in the map, the 2 at index-1, because Maps in Java, inserting a key twice will override its previous value, it will not store duplicate. You can do something like this:

```
for(Integer num : occurrenceList)
    {
        if(sortedMap.containsKey(num)){
          sortedMap.get(num).add(keyList.get(j));
        }else{
          sortedMap.put(num, Arrays.asList(keyList.get(j)));
        }
        j++;
    }

    //puts the key values in another arraylist in the sorted order from the sortedMap
    for(List<Key> s : sortedMap.values())
    {
        Collections.sort(s, new Comparator<Key>(){
           public int compare(Key k1, Key k2){
               return k1.getKey() - k2.getKey();
           }
        });
        temp.addAll(s);
    }
```

And declare **sortedMap** like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Key>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Key>>();
```

Comment: I tried this but get a problem when I do the Collections.sort(s);. It says required type is List <T> and that I have provided List <Key>.

Comment: Yes, it requires the Key class to implement the Comparable interface. You can learn how to implement it [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/comparable.html).

Comment: I have made a change, above we can also pass a Comparator, try it, but do import the comparator first.

Comment: This time I get "Cannot resolve method 'getKey' in 'Key'", i guess this is because the getKey() method is created in my class HashElement and therefore it can't find the method

Comment: Don't do this. `k1.getKey() - k2.getKey()` as it is not good practice and won't always work.  Do this  `Integer.compare(k1.getKey(),k2.getKey())`

Comment: Then the keyList variable, should be of type ArrayList<HashElement<Key>>, not of type Key, and when these elements are sorted, then you can store the keys in a new Collection and return.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to demonstrate some concepts.  I suggest you use it as a guide to understanding how the various capabilities work.  Those can then be applied to your own solution.  It is especially important to use the `Java API Documentation` to research the various Java API features and classes `(streams, interfaces, comparators, etc)` to understand how they are being used.

```
List<Integer> list1 =
                List.of(3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2);       
MySpecialSet<Integer> list = new MySpecialSet<>(list1);

// the enhanced for loop may be used because of the Iterable interface      
for (int v : list) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", v);
}
System.out.println();

// Using an array of Objects
Integer[] ints = { 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6,
        6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

MySpecialSet<Integer> list2 = new MySpecialSet<>(ints);

// This time using an explicit iterator.
Iterator<Integer> it = list2.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", it.next());
}
System.out.println();
```

prints

```
5 3 2 0 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Here is the explanation of the class.  This class will accept either an Array or a List of elements that implement the `Comparable` interface which is required for sorting of the elements.

- this class implements the `Iterable` interface to return an Iterator. This allows the enhanced for loop to operate over the list.
- when the iterator is obtained, either directly or implicitly, it converts the supplied list to meet the requirements.
- first stream the keys and collect them in a map using a frequency count.
- then stream the entryset of that map and sort based first on the frequency and if the frequencies are equal, then the key itself.  And do these in reverse order.
- then, the keys are returned in an internal list to be used by the iterator.

```
class MySpecialSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;
    
    public MySpecialSet(T[] v) {
        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(v));
    }
    
    public MySpecialSet(Collection<T> coll) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(coll);
    }
    
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }
    
    private class MyIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        private Iterator<T> it;
        // comparator to direct the sort for comparing the may entries. First compare
        // on the value (count) then if the count is equal, compare on the key
        Comparator<Entry<T, Long>> comp = Entry
                .<T, Long>comparingByValue()
                .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey()).reversed();
        
        public MyIterator() {
            // This will essentially be a set since no duplicate
            // entries will be present
            List<T> result = list.stream()
                    // frequency count and collect into map
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k,
                            Collectors.counting()))
                    // then stream the entries and sort as explained
                    // above using comparator.
                    .entrySet().stream().sorted(comp)
                    // then collect the keys into a list
                    .map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            it = result.iterator();
        }
        
        // simply use the iterator of the newly created list.
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return it.hasNext();
        }
        
        public T next() {
            return it.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is a little problematic. I am not using a Key array but rather a HashElement array. Hashelement is a class that I created myself. I will update the post with that information.

Comment: I'm not certain the purpose of the HashElement class.  A couple of things.  First, it appears that you are using `Key` as as generic type.  Best practice is to use single uppercase letters `HashElement<K>` to differentiate from an actual type.  Second, it would be very helpful to  understand the complete goal of your task as opposed to a particular, isolated, problem you're are having.  The reason being that it is possible that offered solutions may not be compatible with existing code that isn't provided.

Comment: This is the purpose of the Iterable (copied from my teachers paper): Return an Iterable <Key> -
objects where iteration occurs
over the keys in
order of occurrence. The most
the existing key comes
first, the second most
occurring comes later
etc.